# Loss of precision in float operations, due to exponent differences?

Tags: math, floating-point, precision

I have a program where I represent lengths (in cm) and angles (in radian) as floats. My lengths usually have values between 10 and 100, while my angles usually have values between 0 and 1.

I'm aware that precision will be lost in all floating point operations, but my question is:

Do I loose extra precision because of the magnitude gap between my two numerical realms? Would it be better if I changed my length unit to be meters, such that my usual length values lies between 0.1 and 1, which matches my usual angle values pretty evenly?

Comment: IMO: use cm as this is have less numbers after the decimal

Comment: floating point is nothing more than grade school math should be able to figure this out.  in part it depends on the operations.  with addition as we know from grade school math you have to align the decimal points which is exponent driven the smaller number has its mantissa shoved off into the ether.  but for multiplication for example as we know in grade school math the mantissa's are computed and the upper half of the result retained, the exponents are summed, separately managed, precision is not lost.

Comment: 1.234 * 10^10 + 1.234 * 10^1 with 3 digits of mantissa.  when you align the decimal points you get 1.234 + 0.000 = 1.234.  but multiply  you get 1.523 * 10^11.

Comment: i don’t think so but if you want to use the separate ranges it’s pretty easy to map one to the other and vice versa

Comment: dont see how adding or subtracting the same number from each exponent would affect the math  1.234*10^10 + 1.234*10^1 vs 1.234*10^12 + 1.234*10^3 does not change the precision until you get to a magnitude that is on the edge of exponent maximum, and I assume meters or centimeters you are not measuring distances between planets or the size of the universe.

Comment: How do you use lengths and angles together? Does your program interpret angles as arc length of unit radius? That's the only legitimate case I see for adding angles to lengths directly.

Comment: For example, I have a length along a circle and wan't to know the corresponding angle in radians. So I divide the length by the radius of the circle and get the angle. So, yes, by using radians I interpret angles as arc length of unit radius.

Answer (score 1):

The point of floating point is that the point floats. Changing the magnitudes of numbers does not change the relative errors, except for quantization effects.

A floating point system represents a number *x* with some value *f* and an exponent *e* with some fixed base *b* (*e.g.*, 2 for binary floating point), so that *x* = *f* *b*<sup>*e*</sup>. (Often the sign is separated from *f*, but I am omitting that for simplicity.) If you multiply the numbers being worked with by any power of *b*, addition and subtraction will operate exactly the same (and so will multiplication and division if you correct for the additional factor), up to the bounds of the format.

If you multiply by other numbers, there can be small effects in rounding. When an operation is performed, the result has to be rounded to a fixed number of digits for the *f* portion. This rounding error is a fraction of the least significant digit of *f*. If *f* is near 1, it is larger **relative to *f*** than if *f* is near *2*.

So, if you multiply your numbers by 256 (a power of 2), add, and divide by 256, the results will be the same as if you did the addition directly. If you multiply by 100, add, and divde by 100, there will likely be small changes. After multiplying by 100, some of your numbers will have their *f* parts moved closer to 2, and some will have their *f* parts moved closer to 2.

Generally, these changes are effectively random, and you cannot use such scaling to improve the results. Only in special circumstances can you control these errors.

Comment: "you cannot use such scaling to improve the results".
Except that, as old_timer said, when it comes to addition, I *can* control the loss, by ensuring harmony between the exponents of the two numbers being added.

Comment: @loldrup: You are not being clear. If you want to add *a* and *b* and you “harmonize” the exponents by multiplying one of them, say *b*, to change its exponent and then add, then the result is *a* + *b* • *h* for some *h*. If “harmonized” the exponents properly, that result may have a much smaller rounding error in the addition, but it has a whopping huge error in that it added the wrong value to *a*.

Comment: Agree, I cannot harmonize like that. I can only harmonize by adopting meters as units from the very start of my calculations. Using meters 'natively', so to say.

Comment: @loldrup: That is the same thing as multiplying by a factor, adding, and dividing by a factor, and the answer above applies. Adding in meters, feet, or furlongs is just a matter of scale. It is irrelevant to floating-point except for the effectively random quantization effects.

Comment: Then I fail to see how  a + b • h will add the wrong value to a. I scale my b to be in meters. This scaling has no bad effect, as it happens at precomputation time (by me changing all input values from cm to meter).
Though, now I think of it, representing lengths in meters instead of cm will naturally cut off two digits of precision from the 'significand' of my floating point number. So this might make any precision gained in addition operations moot.

Comment: @foldrup: If *a* is 4 to represent 4 meters and *b* is 3 to represent 3 meters, then the desired result of adding *a* and *b* is 7 for 7 meters. Adding *b* • *h* to *a* will not produce 7 for any value of *h* other than 1, so multiplying *b* to add it to *a* by any value other than 1 produces an incorrect result.

Comment: @foldrup: Changing from cm to m will not “natural cut off two digits of precision from the significand”. In decimal floating point, 257 centimeters would be represented as 2.57 • 10\*\*2, and 2.57 meters would be represented as 2.57 • 10\*\*0. In binary, the significands would change since the factor, 100, is not a power of two. But the number of bits available in the significand is **fixed by the format**. It is not a function of the magnitudes of the numbers. You do not get more bits one way or another. Whether in m or cm, a fixed number of bits is used to represent the significand.

Comment: good point! thanks
though we still seem to talk past one another when it comes to the a + b • h equation. I think that 4m * (3cm / 100) is the same as 4m * 0.03m. Especially since the (3cm / 100) part would never be computed. I'd simply write it as 0.03 when I give the numer as imput to the program.